# $P(X+Y>Z)$ given $X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, probability-inequalities, iid

Given $X, Y, Z$  i.i.d random variables the probability $P(X+Y>Z)$ can be found by the following three approaches:

1. $X+Y-Z > 0$ region cuts the $X Y Z$ volume into two equal volumes as $X+Y-Z=0$ plane passes through origin. Thus, $P(X+Y>Z)=\frac{1}{2}$ which seems doubtful as $X+Y$ is mostly more than $Z$.
2. $$P(X+Y>Z) = E(I_{X+Y>Z}) = E(E(I_{X+Y>Z}|Z))$$
   $$E(E(I_{X+Y>Z}|Z)) = E(P(X+Y>z)) = E((1-F_{X+Y}(z))) = \int_z (1-F_{X+Y}(z))f_{Z}(z)dz$$ 
   where, $$F_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{-\infty} ^{z} \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} f_{X}(k)f_{Y}(h-k)dk$$

It is very complicated to substitute $F_{X+Y}(z)$ in the final expression of $P(X+Y>Z)$. Thus, it's quite difficult to comment on $P(X+Y>Z)$. Please help in this approach to solve it.

3. $E[X] = E[Y] = E[Z]$, because $X, Y, Z$ follow identical, independent distributions.

$E[X + Y] = 2\times E[Z]$,

Intuition says that $P(X+Y>Z)$ thus ought to be 2/3, but I do not know if this is correct, nor how to make this reasoning rigorous.

Help in figuring out which approaches are correct, wrong and why ?

Comment: you should add the self-study tag

Comment: Why so? @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: Note that the conclusions of (1) and (3) can't possibly be correct because they make no reference to the underlying distribution.  First exercise: (a) find a distribution s.t. $X+Y>Z$ almost surely.  (b) find a distribution such that $\mathbb{P}(X+Y>Z) = 1/2$.  This shows the right answer must depend on the underlying distribution.  Regarding approach (2)- unfortunately sometimes being "complicated" doesn't mean "wrong"

Comment: Because this looks like standard bookwork or coursework.

Comment: My intuition says otherwise. Part of this intuition is based on consideration of very simple random variables, such as constants or those that are tiny perturbations of constants. Suppose, for instance, the support of the common distribution is contained within a narrow interval $[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$, with $\epsilon\lt 1/3$.  Then the support of $X+Y$ is contained within $[2-2\epsilon,2+2\epsilon]$, which does not overlap the support of $Z$ at all, whence $\Pr(X+Y\gt Z)=1$. If you negate all variables in this example, $\Pr(X+Y\gt Z)=0$. Moral: *don't guess: do (simple) calculations.*

Comment: Counterexample - if $X,Y,Z\stackrel{i.i.d.}\sim\mathsf Unif(0,1)$ then $\mathbb P(X+Y>Z) = \frac56$, but if they have exponential distribution then the probability is $\frac34$.